# Migrating URLs without titles into a link field (where the link title is optional) without them becoming NULL

Tags: migrations

I'm migrating URLs that don't have corresponding titles into a link field, and when I either don't define the title, or use the default_value plugin to set the default value to '', the value actually gets set to NULL, instead of an empty string, which breaks my link formatter, that expects link titles to be strings (even if the strings are empty):

```yml
    process:
      field_link/title:
        - plugin: default_value
          default_value: ''
```

How can I insert the titles as an empty string, instead of NULL?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution was to create an empty string as a constant, in the migration source, and then reference that:

```
source:
  constants:
    empty: ''

process:
  field_link/title: constants/empty
```

Comment: Nice post, thank you for sharing.